# Keeping track of external git repos merged through `git subtree`

Tags: git, git-subtree

I'm trying to establish a good pattern for managing shared code and external dependencies across several projects.  For reasons well documented elsewhere, using submodules has enough pitfalls that I'm inclined to stay away from it.  As of git 1.8 the subtree command is built in and seems to cover a lot of what I care about, but there are still a few core scenarios that seem to be missing.  I was hoping someone has written some scripts on top of the official subtree feature that fills the gaps.

What I want that seems to be missing is:

- Keep track of what has been added through a subtree, and what branch was specified
- The ability to do `git subtree pull-all` and `push-all`
- As part of the last, the ability to specify whether a subtree should be locked to a specific commit or to the latest commit in a branch.

Are these things built into the command and I'm just missing something in how they're used?
I also have the requirement that this needs to work on Windows, in case that affects anything.

Thanks,

Comment: My compiled-from-official-source `git` version 1.8.1.5 does not have a `git subtree` command. Perhaps it's an add-on or something from the `contrib` bits, or maybe you've got a release candidate (1.8.2-rc<someting>)...

Comment: `git --version` displays `git version 1.8.1.msysgit.1`.  I upgraded from 1.7 something yesterday using the official Windows binaries.  I was originally looking at it from a github repo but it currently has this doc: https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/blob/master/THIS-REPO-IS-OBSOLETE, commenting about it being integrated into git proper.

Comment: No, it’s never been integrated into git – it’s part of the git `contrib` folder – that does not mean that it’s automatically installed. See here: https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/subtree

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that distinction existed.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Hey Joe - you asked this over a year ago.  I'm trying to figure out the exact same thing.  What did you finally settle on?  My main issue is your first bullet - tracking where the subtree came from.  Thanks!

Comment: We've been using submodules.  Since the time that I asked the ability for a submodule to track a branch rather than just a SHA has been added, which helps some. The main thing that ended up pushing me away from subtrees is that the commit history doesn't track well when you're managing changes that are made in both the subtree version as well as the real project--it takes a couple iterations back and forth for a change set to really settle.

Answer (score 0):

No, a command like that does not exist. A command like that is also very hard to implement, as git-subtree does not store where the subtree is coming from as metadata. If you want features like that, I would strongly recommend submodules. They will also require some scripting from your part to achieve what you want, though.

Comment: Working with a detached head seems error prone and it's generally easy enough to get in a state where we can lose work that I thought I should avoid submodules.  I haven't tried using them in anything large, but coworkers have and have strong negative opinions.  When searching on Google for general options for this scenario there aren't many pages I've found that recommend submodules as a good way to go about this.  If it really is better and can be made safe through scripts then I'd be happy to try.

Comment: Also, I've seen things like this, http://endot.org/2012/02/12/git-subtree-tracking-made-easy/, that start to build towards the workflow I was looking for using subtrees.  I was hoping someone had taken it further and with the version that was checked into Git/contrib rather than as a separate fork.

Comment: The detached head state is indeed a little bit dangerous. But You should check which branch you’re on when working on your code and before commiting, anyways.